# Cannot inject InjectionToken to service constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, swagger, swagger-codegen

i need to resolve, why my injectionToken is not being injected in class constructor. I have angular (7.1), code generated from NSwag.

I have already tried putting providers code in both module and component. Thanks for advice.

client.ts

```
export const API_BASE_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('API_BASE_URL');

export class Client implements IClient {
private http: HttpClient;
private baseUrl: string;
protected jsonParseReviver: ((key: string, value: any) => any) | undefined = undefined;
// Removed @Optional for debug purpose
constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) http: HttpClient, @Inject(API_BASE_URL) baseUrl?: string) {
    this.http = http;
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl ? baseUrl : "";
}
}
```

app.module.ts

```
const API_BASE_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('API_BASE_URL');

// providers array
providers: [
    {provide: API_BASE_URL, useValue: 'localhost:1234'},
    Client,
    ArticleService
]
```

article.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ArticleService {

  client: Client;

  constructor(client: Client) {
    this.client = client;
  }
}


ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule) 
[Client -> InjectionToken API_BASE_URL]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Client -> InjectionToken API_BASE_URL]: 
   NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken API_BASE_URL!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Client -> InjectionToken API_BASE_URL]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Client -> InjectionToken API_BASE_URL]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken API_BASE_URL!
```

Comment: You should import `API_BASE_URL` in `app.module.ts` from `client.ts` and not to declare the same token twice

Comment: Thanks much, solved my problem.

Comment: where should i import it i am going through this error

Comment: just somewhere put a definition of injection token and import where needed

Answer (score 0):

In your `environment.ts` file you should add an entry for `API_BASE_URL` as follows:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  API_BASE_URL: "https://localhost:44336"
};
```

Likewise in your `environment.prod.ts` add an entry for your production `API_BASE_URL`.

Next in your `main.ts` file import the `API_BASE_URL` declaration from your `client.ts` and add the `API_BASE_URL` to the providers so that your `main.ts` looks something like the following:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from "./app/app.module";
import { API_BASE_URL } from "./app/client.ts";

console.log(environment);

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

export function getBaseUrl() {
  return document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
}

const providers = [
  { provide: API_BASE_URL, useValue: environment.API_BASE_URL },
  { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl, deps: [] }
];

platformBrowserDynamic(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```